# Copy and rename music files with batch file

Tags: cmd, copy, rename, batch-rename

I have a music directory in the format of D:%Artist%%Album%\Song.mp3. from here, i have created a script that prompts for an artist folder and then copies all MP3s into a new folder with the same name after stripping any album folders

```
D:\%Artist%\%Album%\Song.mp3 into D:\MP3s\%Artist%\Song.mp3
```

What i'd really like to do is rename all song files in the new location to include the Album name followed by an underscore. if there a song is in the Artist root folder, it should just have an underscore before the song name to indcate it wasn't within an album folder.

```
D:\%Artist%\%Album%\%Song% into D:\MP3s\%Artist%\%Album%_Song.mp3 OR D:\MP3s\%Artist%\_Song.mp3
```

the following code is what i'm using to get all songs from all subfolders into a single folder, but i am unsure on how to get the albun name setup for a rename process. this is my current code

```
SET /P Artist=What is the artist folder to copy?
pushd D:\Music\%Artist%
for /r %%a in (*.mp3) do (
COPY "%%a" "D:\Music\MP3s\%%~nxa"
)
popd
```

Comment: Is `%SONG$` a directory name or a .mp3 filename? Should I read this as `D:\%Artist%\%Album%\%Song%` where `%SONG%` might be `Shine.mp3`?

Comment: %Song% should be read as a file name

Comment: use a proper renaming tool https://github.com/75lb/renamer

Comment: @Lloyd so by "a proper renaming tool", you mean a tool that you wrote instead of using the pre-installed OS supplied tools?

Comment: no i don't @KurtSchwob, i mean a proper renaming tool instead of the untested DOS scripts suggested here.. renaming files is risky and potentially destructive if you make a mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the following code works in my case. if you have a different file structure depth, then you will need to adjust the tokens. i also found that if the script was run multiple times for the same artist, it would copy over the files but not rename them, so i have added in a file check to see if the final filename is already present.

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET /P Artist=What is the artist folder to copy?
MD "D:\Music\MP3s\%Artist%"
PUSHD D:\Music\%Artist%
FOR /r %%a in (*.mp3) DO (
FOR /f "tokens=4,5 delims=\" %%I IN ("%%a") DO (
SET Song=%%J
SET Album=%%I
if "!Song!" == "" (
SET Song=!Album!
SET Album=
)
SET NewFileName="!Album!_!Song!"
)
CD D:\Music\MP3s\%Artist%
IF NOT EXIST !NewFileName! (
COPY "%%a" "D:\Music\MP3s\%Artist%\%%~nxa"
REN "D:\Music\MP3s\%Artist%\%%~nxa" !NewFileName!
)
)
POPD
```